# Getting html code from magento cache

Tags: php, magento, caching

I am getting a html tag `h1` from the magento cache even though I have disabled all the cache types from `admin panel - system -> cache managment` and I have also done flush magento cache and flush cache storage, cleaned up the browser history and cache too.

On seaching in the magento directory the code is coming from two files:

```
/magento/var/cache
/magento/var/session
```

If I delete all the files under these 2 folders and refresh the page they are getting generated again, these are the search results for those `h1` tags in editor :

```
Unable to open /var/www/magento/var/cache/mage--6/mage---176_CONFIGURATION_FILES_ACCESS_LEVEL_VERIFICATION
Unable to open /var/www/magento/var/cache/mage--6/mage---internal-metadatas---176_CONFIGURATION_FILES_ACCESS_LEVEL_VERIFICATION
Unable to open /var/www/magento/var/session/sess_crnul2mlmkm08h4diavvv55mf6
```

Comment: Not understanding the question. What's in the cache, or for that matter displayed while the cache is disabled, is generated by templates. Wouldn't you change the templates so they generate the proper html code in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value from cache you need to use cache key instead of element tag.

```
$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
$cache->save(date("d-m-Y"), "example", array("example_cache"), 10);
```

Retrive value of cache with cache key:

```
print_r($cache->load("example"));
```